# cellForRowAtIndexPath does not call

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Interesting thing. If I set height at 0 for some cell:

```
    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (indexPath.row == 0) {
     return 0;
    } else {
return 10;
}
```

than -

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
will not call for that index (for indexPath.row == 0).
```

I see this flow only when it test on `iPhone`(IOS 9.3). (On `iPad` this method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will call)!

Do you know why we have different flow?

Comment: It should call `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` only if the cell is visible. So in theory, it shouldn't be called on iPad. Same behavior with `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Larme, Yes I agree with you, but at real world it works another